# how to find out how many bytes I've written to bytebuffer (new to java)

Tags: java, android, nio

I've tried reading the documentation, but there is no explanation of what is limit, mark etc. Annyoing thing is that the ByteBuffer.limit function's description says that it returns limit. now what is limit? Is it same or different from capacity...

End of the day, I want to know how many bytes I've 'put' into the buffer

If i allocate buffer with size 1024 and write the word "hello" into it. How can I get the result of 5 bytes written to the buffer?

Thanks

Comment: If you're new to Java, what brings you to one of the most difficult APIs in the JDK, the NIO library?

Comment: i'm making an android app... and found the bytebuffer class while reading examples... but this does not answer my question

Comment: Sure thing, a question is not an answer. As you are a newbie, there is a chance you have stumbled upon the wrong API for your mission.

Comment: I'm trying to read incoming packets over bluetooth socket. This is an image file. When I see END of file header, I want to write the buffer out to sd card. Is there another api better suited for this (in java/android)?

Comment: I am not an expert on Android (your question wasn't tagged with it -- if it were, I wouldn't be here), but in regular Java we use the java.io API, which is stream-oriented and an order of magnitude simpler to use. NIO is more like an SPI and not an end-user API. But in Android things may be different.

Comment: There is [*plenty* of documentation on this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to know is explained in the [java.io.Buffer documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html)

> A *buffer's capacity* is the number of elements it contains. The
>   capacity of a buffer is never negative and never changes.
>
> A *buffer's limit* is the index of the first element that should not
>   be read or written. A buffer's limit is never negative and is never
>   greater than its capacity.
>
> A *buffer's position* is the index of the next element to be read or
>   written. A buffer's position is never negative and is never greater
>   than its limit.
>
> **Invariants**
>
> The following invariant holds for the mark, position, limit, and
>   capacity values:
>
> ```
> 0 <= mark <= position <= limit <= capacity
> ```
>
> A newly-created buffer always has a position of zero and a mark that
>   is undefined. The initial limit may be zero, or it may be some other
>   value that depends upon the type of the buffer and the manner in which
>   it is constructed. Each element of a newly-allocated buffer is
>   initialized to zero.
>
> **Marking and resetting**
>
> A buffer's mark is the index to which its position will be reset when
>   the reset method is invoked. The mark is not always defined, but when
>   it is defined it is never negative and is never greater than the
>   position. If the mark is defined then it is discarded when the
>   position or the limit is adjusted to a value smaller than the mark. If
>   the mark is not defined then invoking the reset method causes an
>   InvalidMarkException to be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

The write() method *returns* the numbered bytes transferred. You're overcomplicating this.